# jQuery Tabs Mismatching Fragment Identifier

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I hate to do this, but I just can't identify what I am doing wrong in the code here?

I have been using jQuery tabs for a long time so I'm know nube. I know what this error means too, but I don't see the problem.

Can you lend me a fresh pair of eyes and tell me what's wrong?

```
<div id="Autotab">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#autotabs-1">Register a Theme Function</a></li>
        <li><a href="#autotabs-2">Define a Theme Function</a></li>
        <li><a href="#autotabs-3">Call a Theme Function</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="#autotabs-1">.. </div>
    <div id="#autotabs-2">.. </div>
    <div id="#autotabs-3">.. </div>
</div>
```

I'm also running the JavaScript:

```
$("#Autotab").tabs();
```

Comment: Your div ids should be without hash.

Comment: What does this error mean, exactly?

Comment: In this case it is saying that the id of the container specified by the href can't be found. Also, although I don't know the guts of jQuery, I believe it uses document fragments to reduce processing time, so that would explain the 'fragment' part of the error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use these without hash

```
<div id="autotabs-1">.. </div>
<div id="autotabs-2">.. </div>
<div id="autotabs-3">.. </div>
```

Comment: Ah snap! To the rescue! I'd looked over that so many times. What a duh moment. Thanks for the help.